# Shortest path in graph - upgrade an algorithm

Tags: algorithms, graphs

We are given a graph with $n$ vertices, $m$ edges, and path edge costs of $x$. For vertices without a direct path that are distant exactly one neighbor, we can add new edge with edge cost $y$. Our task is to find shortest path (i.e minimum cost) between the start vertex and all others vertices.

I have developed an algorithm, but I would like to create something faster than adding edges to the graph (via breadth-first search) and [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). Here are a couple examples:

*Example 1 Input:* For $x=3$, $y=1$

[image: Example 1 Graph]

*Possible $y$ paths included:*

[image: Example 1 Graph with y]

*Output*: cost of shortest path from start node to node $i$ (assume that from start node to start node is 0)

> 1: 0
>   2: 2
>   3: 2
>   4: 1
>   5: 1
>   6: 3

*Example 2 Input*: For $x=3, y=2$

[image: Example 2 Graph]

*Output*:

> 1: 0
>   2: 3
>   3: 3
>   4: 2
>   5: 5

Comment: I don't understand the output of your second example at all. Is there a typo?

Comment: n = 5, m = 5, start vertex is 1, x = 3, y = 2. We have edges from $v_i$ to $v_j$, i will write it in pairs : $(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5), (3,1)$. So in output we have got that minimal costs to drive from start vertex ($V_1$) to $v_i$ is  for $i = 1..5 : (0,3,3,2,5)$. If you have more question, please ask.

Comment: I see ... I missed the "no direct path" in the problem statement.

Comment: Are you sure you're adding the edges to the graph reasonably efficiently? You should be able to do this in time $O(E')$, where $E'$ is the number of edges in the new graph. (I actually suspect that the best algorithm doesn't construct a new graph, but works on the original graph, but I can't figure out a good way to do this.)

Comment: Can you write something about adding edges in $O(E')$ time ? It's better than brute BFS. We will modified it later.

Comment: You can put all the edges in a hash table. Then go through the vertices $v$, and for each vertex $v$, if two neighbors of $v$ aren't connected already, add an edge between them.

Comment: Ok, nice idea. Our complexity is now O(E' + E'logV) - it's good but still not fast enough :(

Comment: One approach to this is to try to simulate doing Dijkstra's algorithm on the larger graph without actually building the graph.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't know how to do it. You want to simulate creating edges when Dijkstra's algorithm is running ? Or you mean something else? Can you write more about your idea?

Comment: It's a very vague idea, and I don't have time to work it out. The idea is not to introduce any new edges, but to come up with an algorithm so that the $i$'th step of the new algorithm gives the same set of visited nodes and the same distances to the nodes as the $i$'th step of the Dijkstra's algorithm on the expanded graph. You might have to introduce several classes of different nodes: unvisited, visited as an intermediate step on a new edge, and visited.

Comment: Just as a side note in first graph you don't need to run dijkstra at all, just a simple BFS is enough, also if you just looking for size of shortest path, may be you can improve it without extra computation. at least there is a simple and very fast approximation.

Comment: Did you ever solve your problem?